# Can't upload .sql file

Tags: apache2, mysql, phpmyadmin

Environment:

- Ubuntu 14.04 (local dev machine running under VirtualBox)
- Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
- phpMyAdmin 4.0.10deb1

I'm getting the below error. I've been reading the manual and searching posts but none of the suggestions are helping. I'm pretty new to Linux and Apache so I could just be not understanding something.

```
Warning: Unknown: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp) is not within the allowed path(s): (/usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/php-gettext/:/usr/share/javascript/) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: File upload error - unable to create a temporary file in Unknown on line 0

No data was received to import. Either no file name was submitted, or the file size exceeded the maximum size permitted by your PHP configuration. See FAQ 1.16
```

The error is coming form phpMyAdmin. I have tried to upload via the command line and it just hangs until I quit.

I made the following changes to `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`

```
post_max_size = #>db size = 60M
memory_limit = #>post_max_size = 256M
upload_max_filezise = #<post_max_size 20M
```

And have tried

1. Changed DocumentRoot in /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
2. tried setting php.ini - upload_tmp_dir
3. tried adding the folder the .sql file is in to apache.conf php_admin_value open_basedir - this only changed the error message.

One thing I did a long time ago was to have apache run under my user account. I'm wondering if this isn't the problem.

Comment: what about this [link](http://www.howtoforge.com/forums/showthread.php?t=61333)? and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15958419/while-using-dynamic-vhosts-with-dnsmasq-fixing-phpmyadmin-open-basedir-restrict)?

Comment: Thank you again Letizia. The first link gave me the necessary clues. Modifying 2 lines in /etc/phpmyadmin/apache2.con fixed it. I would like to give you credit for the answer but cannot in a comment so please add an answer if you wish. I'm going to post specific in an answer.

Comment: I incorrectly type the name of the file above. It is cpache.conf (not apache2.conf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See first link in [@Litizia](https://askubuntu.com/users/290569/letizia) comment above for the post that helped me solve the problem.

Specific changes to `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` that solved the problem for me are:

```
under <IfModule mod_php.c>
```

First:

> **change**
>   `php_value include_path .`
>   **to:**
>   `php_value include_path .:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear`

Second:

> **Change**
>   `php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/php-gettext/:/usr/share/javascript/`
>   **to:**
>   `php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/php-gettext/:/usr/share/javascript/:/usr/share/php:/tmp/`

Comment: And to put it into effect, `service apache2 reload`

I don't understand why this isn't the default in the packages. I have seen this issue on several servers (including shared hosting where we don't have root/admin access!)

Answer (score 0):

Following the suggestion in this [link](http://www.howtoforge.com/forums/showthread.php?t=61333) we get the answer.

Let's see some explanations.

According to php documentation [open_basedir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir):

> When a script tries to access the filesystem, for example using
>   include, or fopen(), the location of the file is checked. When the
>   file is outside the specified directory-tree, PHP will refuse to
>   access it.

In order to allow your script to access /tmp and other path you need, modify your /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf and add:

```
  php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/php-gettext/:/usr/share/javascript/:/usr/share/php:/tmp/
```

Always according to the php documentation [include_path](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path):

> Specifies a list of directories where the require, include, fopen(),
>   file(), readfile() and file_get_contents() functions look for files.
>   The format is like the system's PATH environment variable: a list of
>   directories separated with a colon in Unix or semicolon in Windows.

Using apache configuration file is possible to set the variable using the directive [php_value](http://php.net/manual/it/configuration.changes.php):

```
    php_value name value
```

In your case, add:

```
   php_value include_path .:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear
```

At the end, restart your apache.